# Stuck on 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

I have two machines that are *more or less* exactly the same.  Both were deployed as 20.04 LTS and run mirrors of the same software. Recently while performing system maintenance I noticed that they are running slightly different versions:

- Machine A: `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64)`
- Machine B: `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64)`

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is identical on both machines.  Running `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` does not help.

What could be causing this?

Comment: If they are fully updated, they are the same.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - no, they are not.  The versions are different as are the versions of various packages. For instance, one is on MySQL 8.0.25 and the other is on 8.0.21.

Comment: Judging from the kernel version, none of them is updated. The current version is **5.4.0-73-generic**. There must be something wrong with the update mirrors. Have you tried changing them? Also, do not use `apt-get upgrade`. For full system upgrades, use `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: @Stormlord - Yes I've tried switch to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ and makes no difference. I think `dist-upgrade` is a bit dangerous for a production server that's currently stable and I don't think that should be necessary to receive those minor subversions as I've never had to do that before.  I haven't run that on either machine anyway so it doesn't explain why there should be a difference.

Comment: Have you compared the output of `sudo apt update` on both systems?  Have you compared all the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files on both systems?

Comment: @Terrance - yes.  They are all identical.  The only difference at all I can observe is the order of the repositories queried by apt. Correct me if I'm wrong but I can't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: fyi - we just ran `apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` which seems to have brought things up to date.  I'm still interested in an answer that explains what might have led to this situation.

Comment: As long as the default repos are the same, the order in which they run would not make a difference.  However, the frequency in which they both check for updates does make a difference and how the updates are handled by each system.  If they are both GUI Desktop systems check in Settings -> Software & Updates -> Updates tab and compare.